# Find a shortest way between nodes in graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have the structure:

[image]

Each node in graph may have more than 2 links. I want to find a shortest way with node `1` and `13`. But I have no idea how to do that. Maybe some algorithm for this issue exist?

Answer (score 2):

I think doing some research into [breadth-first graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) will help you quite a bit.

In essence, you are going to use a queue `Q` and you are going to push pairs onto `Q` of the form `(Node key, distance from Node 1)`. A basic algorithm to accomplish what you are after will look like this:

```
pushback (1,0) onto Q
while Q is nonempty
  pop the pair (m,n) off of Q
  for each of the Nodes i adjacent to Node m 
    if i == 13
      return n+1 because we are done
    else
      pushback (i,n+1) onto Q
```

Of course there are quite a few ways to speed this up, like by making sure you never push the same Node onto `Q` more than once.